# run sml console at emacs - searching for program: no such file or directory?

Tags: emacs, installation, sml

I installed SML on Ubuntu 12.04.

Here is more info:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ sml -version
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.75 [built: Mon Sep  2 23:36:16 2013]
```

And added to emacs this package:

```
M x list-packages  + Enter
```

find `sml-mode` and install by mouse click.
But when I tried write easy `.sml` file I want to open sml console at emacs.

I press `C c + C s` => I see `SML command: sml` and press `Enter`.

And see this message:

```
Searching for program: no such file or directory
```

Instead of opening sml console.

I couldn't figure out why this happen?

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

**Update:**

Here is my `which sml`:

```
/usr/local/SML/bin/sml
```

and emacs version - `GNU Emacs 24.3.1`
Installed from [here](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs) but only for emacs24, not for emacs-snapshot.

Comment: Works fine for me. What's your Emacs version?
Also make sure that `which sml` and `(getenv "PATH")` are compatible.

Comment: @abo-abo I updated question. `which sml and (getenv "PATH") are compatible` - can you explain more how to check this statement?

Comment: `(getenv "PATH")` you should evaluate with `M-:`. Or just paste this code in `*scratch*` and press `C-j` 
while at the end of statement. This tells you Emacs' view of $PATH.
Your problem is probably that /usr/local/SML/bin/ is not on the $PATH. You can add this to
`~/.profile` or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that the `sml` executable isn't on the PATH that Emacs sees.
And you can launch `sml` from `bash` probably because you modify path
in `~/.bashrc`.

1. Option 1: modify PATH
   In `~/.profile` (you'll need to log out once):

   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/SML/bin/
2. Option 2: create link

   sudo ln -s /usr/local/SML/bin/sml /usr/bin/sml
3. Option 3: apt installs for me sml to /usr/bin/ (Emacs knows this path)

   sudo apt-get install smlnj

Answer (score 11):

Option 4: Eval the following with: <kbd>C-M-:</kbd> `(setq exec-path (cons "/usr/local/SML/bin" exec-path))` <kbd>return/enter</kbd> or put it into `$home/.emacs` to make it persist over all sessions.

Answer (score 4):

Just elaborating on the steps mentioned by the Bleeding fingers:

Step1: Launch emacs from terminal.

step2: Press ctrl+x+f.

step3: You will get something in the bottom saying "Find a file:~/" then there write "/.emacs".

step4: Paste this line "setq exec-path (cons "/usr/local/SML/bin" exec-path))" in that.

step5: Press Ctrx+x+s to save the changes and then restart the emacs.